# Prevent a style (accidently loaded globally) from applying to a control

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to use `TextField` of Fluent UI.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@fluentui/react';

class Try extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TextField label="With auto" multiline autoAdjustHeight/>
        );
    }
}

export default Try;
```

Then, I realize that there is no space between the label and the text area. I check the CSS and understand that it is due to a `label { margin-bottom: 5px; height: 22px }` defined in `index.css` of another component `XXX`. Many tags and classes are defined in `XXX/index.css` such as `form`, `label`, `input`, `button`. Because I have `import ./index.css` in the component `XXX` and `import ../XXX/index.css` in several other components, `XXX/index.css` is loaded globally. And this `XXX/index.css` disturbs `label` of TextField of Fluent UI inside `Try`.

Does anyone know what I could do to `Try` component such that its TextField is not disturbed by `XXX/index.css`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may do this.

create another css file and load that css globally or just change that particular css only this the following.

```
label:not(#dont-apply-label *) { margin-bottom: 5px; height: 22px }
```

Now when you call the Fluent-Ui component, give a id

```
<TextField id="dont-apply-label" label="With auto" multiline autoAdjustHeight/>
```

This might not be best solution out of the box. But worth trying.

Another way can be triggering with class name like the following but not sure gonna work.

```
label:not(.ms-TextField *) { margin-bottom: 5px; height: 22px }
```

Comment: I'm not sure your solution works, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74945556/safe-way-to-prevent-a-style-accidently-loaded-globally-from-applying-to-a-butt