# Safe way to prevent a style (accidently loaded globally) from applying to a button

Tags: css, css-selectors

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74941512/702977), I want a button with ID `dont-apply-global-style-1` to not apply `width: 130px`, thus I change the css rule `label, input, button: { width: 130px }` to :

```
label,
input,
button:not(#dont-apply-global-style-1 *) {
    width: 130px;
}
```

But it does not work. The following button still applies `width: 130px`:

[image]

Additionally, I see toggles (`Toggle`) without the id `dont-apply-global-style-1` also applies `width: 130px`, it seems that these rules have priority now, this did not happen before.

(a toggle without the id `dont-apply-global-style-1` before changing the rule:)
[image]

(a toggle without the id `dont-apply-global-style-1` after changing the rule:)
[image]

Could anyone tell me what's the safe way to private a button element from a global rule?

Comment: you have `#id *` so u selecting all elements in the `#id` not itself. try to remove the `*`

Comment: I tried to remove `*`, it did prevent the button from applying the rule. But the problem with the toggle still remained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are selecting all element inside `#dont-apply-global-style`. The reason is the `*` selector. So it will still apply it style to the the `button` element.

Your second problem happends, because `:not()` and some other [pseudo selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_is_not_and_has_exceptions) will add the css specificity inside its rules to the total specificity. So your final specificity will be `1-0-1`.

You can lower it with the `:where()` pseudo selector. Its specificity, inside it, [will not be added to the total specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_where_exception).

```css
button:where(:not(#c)) {
  width: 130px;
}

.b {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button>a</button>
<button class="b">b</button>
<button id="c">c</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. It shows this: https://ibb.co/6tgJt80

Comment: you missed the `:` before `not`